# Цикл While при обработке данных в БД

Tags: php, while

Я беру из базы данных строки соответствующие определенному Sale_id, в которых есть sum и высчитываю определенные процент из этих sum, по следующему принципу если Общий SUM всех выбранных строк, больше определенного числа то каждая sum каждой строки умножается на определенную величину и результат по каждой строке записывается в поле point. Вот код

```html
function update_point ($arr)
{
    global $link;
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $arr['name']);
    $sale_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $arr['sale_id']); //безопасность 
    
    if (!empty($name))
    {
        $query = "SELECT SUM(sum), sum FROM sale WHERE sale_id='$sale_id' ";
        $q_point=mysqli_query($link, $query);
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_point))
        {
           $SUM = $result['SUM(sum)'];

        if ($SUM<1000)
        {
            $point = $result['sum']* 0.03;
            $query2 = "UPDATE sale SET points='$point'  WHERE sale_id='$sale_id'"; // баллый за процедуру
            mysqli_query($link, $query2);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($SUM>=1000 && $SUM<3000)
            {
                $point = $result['sum']* 0.05;
                $query2 = "UPDATE sale SET points='$point'  WHERE sale_id='$sale_id'"; // баллый за процедуру
                mysqli_query($link, $query2);
            }
            else
            {
                $point=$result['sum']*0.07;
                $query2 = "UPDATE sale SET points='$point'  WHERE sale_id='$sale_id'"; // баллый за процедуру
                mysqli_query($link, $query2);
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Но у меня почему то код, умножает на определенную величину sum не каждой строки, а только первой и получившееся значение вставляет уже в каждую строку. Мне же нужно, чтобы в каждую строку вставлялось значение соответствующее sum этой строки. Подскажите в чем моя ошибка

Comment: Понял спасибо. А как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы можете в запросах прямо считать новую сумму каждой строки: `UPDATE sale SET points= points * 0.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно причина в том что вы обновляете значение для всех $sale_id, т.е. проблема в этих строках:

```
UPDATE sale SET points='$point'  WHERE sale_id='$sale_id'
```

Вместо $sale_id должен быть непосредственно id обновляемой записи в таблице.

Примерное решение:

```
<?php
function update_point ($arr)
{
    global $link;
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $arr['name']);
    $sale_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $arr['sale_id']); //безопасность 
    
    if (empty($name)) return;
    $query = "SELECT SUM(sum), sum, id FROM sale WHERE sale_id='$sale_id' ";
    $q_point=mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_point))
    {
        $SUM = $result['SUM(sum)'];
        if ($SUM<1000)
        {
            $point = $result['sum']* 0.03;
            $query2 = "UPDATE sale SET points='$point'  WHERE sale_id='$result[id]'"; // баллый за процедуру
            mysqli_query($link, $query2);
        } else {
            if ($SUM>=1000 && $SUM<3000)
            {
                $point = $result['sum']* 0.05;
                $query2 = "UPDATE sale SET points='$point'  WHERE sale_id='$result[id]'"; // баллый за процедуру
                mysqli_query($link, $query2);
            } else {
                $point=$result['sum']*0.07;
                $query2 = "UPDATE sale SET points='$point'  WHERE sale_id='$result[id]'"; // баллый за процедуру
                mysqli_query($link, $query2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Egomaniac вам действительно помог этот ответ?  И какой же тут id получается: `SELECT SUM(sum), sum, id ...`? Вы же понимаете, что этот запрос возращает ОДНУ строку?

Answer (score 1):

В вашей выборке:

```
SELECT SUM(sum), sum FROM sale WHERE sale_id='$sale_id'
```

только одна строка, так как `SUM(sum)` группирует ее и, собственно, показывает вам общую сумму. Чтобы теперь изменить все строки, берите каждое поле и умножайте на вычисленное значение:

```
//...
if (!empty($name)) {
    $query = "SELECT SUM(sum), sum FROM sale WHERE sale_id='$sale_id' ";
    $q_point = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_point)) {
        $SUM = $result['SUM(sum)'];
    }
    $point = $SUM < 1000 ? 0.03 : ($SUM < 3000 ? 0.05 : 0.07);
    $query2 = "UPDATE sale SET points = points * $point WHERE sale_id = '$sale_id'";
    mysqli_query($link, $query2);
}
//...
```